# All subsequent calls to Neo4j freezes after handling a ClientException from @Index(unique=true)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a Spring boot application that has an Entity with an uniqueness constraint on a field.

im running spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, bolt-driver and the neo4j 3.2 docker image.

When i run my IT tests, i first persist some data, then i try to persist the same data to get the constraint to trigger.

The uniqueness constraint kicks in as expected in and a ClientException is thrown. This is caught and a proper exception is returned to the client.

Then in the following test i just try to save some data and suddenly the server just freezes when it runs the save() in the GraphRepository.

**So my question is why does neo4j completly freeze in my case in all following transactions after a ClientException has been thrown due to a uniqueness constraint has kicked in. Logs say nothing, neo4j debug.log says nothing.**

If i run each test separate, they both pass. Run together, it freezes neo4j in the test after the constaint has been tested.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<groupId>se.andolf</groupId>
<artifactId>lift</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>lift-api</module>
    <module>lift-service</module>
    <module>lift-app</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Ingalls-SR3</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
    <neo4j-ogm.version>2.1.2</neo4j-ogm.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Ingalls-SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.andolf</groupId>
            <artifactId>lift-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.andolf</groupId>
            <artifactId>lift-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.andolf</groupId>
            <artifactId>lift-service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jmnarloch</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.11</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report-integration</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>coveralls</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                    <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

lift-service/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>lift</artifactId>
    <groupId>se.andolf</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>lift-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.andolf</groupId>
        <artifactId>lift-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jmnarloch</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

session bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "se.andolf")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        LOG.debug("Loading session factory");
        return new SessionFactory("se.andolf");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

CategoryController.class

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = { "Categories" })
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping(method=PUT, value="/categories")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> add(
        @RequestBody Category category, HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
        final Long id = categoryService.save(category);
        final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setLocation(new URI(request.getRequestURL().toString() + "/" + id));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

CategoryService.class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {
    private static Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CategoryService.class);

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public Long save(Category category){
        final CategoryEntity categoryEntity = new CategoryEntity(category.getName());

        try {
            return categoryRepository.save(categoryEntity).getId();
        } catch (ClientException e) {
            LOG.error("Category " + category.getName() + " exists select another name", e);
            throw new NodeExistsException("Category " + category.getName() + " exists please select another name");
        }
    }
}
```

CategoryEntity.class

```
@NodeEntity
public class CategoryEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique=true)
    private String name;

    public CategoryEntity() {
    }

    public CategoryEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ogm.properties

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver
URI=bolt://neo4j:password@localhost
connection.pool.size=150
indexes.auto=assert
```

last rows in the travic-ci log

```
2017-05-28 08:58:34.316 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.n.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver   : No current transaction, starting a new one

2017-05-28 08:58:34.317 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.n.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver   : Native transaction: org.neo4j.driver.internal.ExplicitTransaction@7e0a0bb1

2017-05-28 08:58:34.317 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession       : Thread 20: Transaction, tx id: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction@53533858

2017-05-28 08:58:34.318 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Beginning Transaction [org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction@53533858] on Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@730479f]

2017-05-28 08:58:34.318 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound Session [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession@730479f] for Neo4j OGM transaction

2017-05-28 08:58:34.318 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.d.n.t.Neo4jTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction

2017-05-28 08:58:34.319 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : context initialised with 0 relationships

2017-05-28 08:58:34.319 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : visiting: se.andolf.entities.CategoryEntity@7a132ac9

2017-05-28 08:58:34.319 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : se.andolf.entities.CategoryEntity@7a132ac9 has changed

2017-05-28 08:58:34.319 DEBUG 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper  : mapping references declared by: se.andolf.entities.CategoryEntity@7a132ac9 

2017-05-28 08:58:34.320  INFO 7082 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`CategoryEntity`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, row.type as type with params {rows=[{nodeRef=-2048076489, type=node, props={name=Arms}}]}



No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

The build has been terminated
```

Full log can be found here:
[Travis-ci build log](https://travis-ci.org/Tandolf/lift/builds/236844600)

CategoriesControllerIT.class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT)
public class CategoriesControllerIT {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn409ConflictIfCategoryNameExists(){

        final Category category = new Category("Arms");
        final String id = put(category);

        given()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                .body(category)
            .when()
                .put("/categories")
            .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());

        deleteCategory(id);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSaveCategory(){

        final Category category = new Category("Arms");

        final String header = given()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                .body(category)
            .when()
                .put("/categories")
            .then()
            .assertThat()
                .statusCode(201)
                .header("Location", is(notNullValue()))
                .extract().response().getHeader("Location");

        deleteCategory(UriUtil.extractLastPath(header));
    }

    private String put(Category category) {
        try {
            final String header = given().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE).body(category).put("/categories").getHeader("Location");
            return UriUtil.extractLastPath(header);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

command to run neo4j as an docker for the IT-tests

```
docker run -d --name neo4j --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --env=NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password neo4j:3.2
```

This is only en excerpt of the full code base, i have pasted in what i think is relevant. The full code can be found here:

[Lift-app](https://github.com/Tandolf/lift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting help on the neo4j-user slack the problem was that the drivers had problems closing the sessions when the transaction was closed.

This got fixed in version 2.1.3 of the bolt-driver in the neo4j-ogm.

So bumping the ogm version from 2.1.2 -> 2.1.3 resolved this issue.

related issue: [Make rollback close bolt session when transaction is closed](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/pull/364)

related issue for the java-driver: [java-driver version 1.3.1](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/wiki/1.3-changelog#131)